# Restrict putting oversized object into Guava cache

Tags: java, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

Is there a way to restrict putting object which is greater than a given size.

Comment: And how would you determine that size? You cannot reliably determine the size in bytes of a POJO since it is entirely implementation dependent (even if the POJO itself is pretty well defined, CPU alignment constraints are out of the scope of even the JVM spec)

Comment: @fge I thought of using java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the entry when its oversized? Do you throw an exception (e.g. from the `Weigher`) or is it loaded but not cached?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `LoadingCache`, easy: just make your `CacheLoader` throw an exception if the loaded-in object is too big.

If you're using a non-loading cache, then no. There is no facility to veto cache updates.

Comment: I want to use it when I put it into the cache. Implement in load/reload methods seems not helping me there.

Comment: @Eranda Huh? The sole purpose of the load method is "putting things into the cache". If you write your own load method, you can implement any rules that you want.

Comment: @rmlan I want to check whether there is OOTB support like setting the size. Seems there is not. Thanks.